# Android OpenCV Drawing Hough Lines

Tags: android, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying to use OpenCV on an android phone to detect lines. I modified the 'Tutorial 1 Basic - 2. Use OpenCV Camera' sample. I am also using [Hough Line Transform](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) as an example.
However, I am getting weird numbers (at least what I believe to be weird numbers) for the points. In the range 1000 to -1000 for b.

I don't fully understand the code (mostly the part about adding/subtracting 1000 * (a or -b)).

In the end I do not see the lines at all.

Could anyone give me a hand? Also let me know if you need more information.

```
capture.retrieve(mGray, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_GREY_FRAME);
Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
Imgproc.HoughLines(mIntermediateMat, mLines, 1, Math.PI/180, 100);

Scalar color = new Scalar(0, 0, 255);

double[] data;
double rho, theta;
Point pt1 = new Point();
Point pt2 = new Point();
double a, b;
double x0, y0;
for (int i = 0; i < mLines.cols(); i++)
{
    data = mLines.get(0, i);
    rho = data[0];
    theta = data[1];
    a = Math.cos(theta);
    b = Math.sin(theta);
    x0 = a*rho;
    y0 = b*rho;
    pt1.x = Math.round(x0 + 1000*(-b));
    pt1.y = Math.round(y0 + 1000*a);
    pt2.x = Math.round(x0 - 1000*(-b));
    pt2.y = Math.round(y0 - 1000 *a);
    Core.line(mIntermediateMat, pt1, pt2, color, 3);
}

Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

if (Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp))
    return bmp;

bmp.recycle();
return null;
```

Comment: can u post the complete code pls
tanx regard Giuseppe

Answer (score 35):

I am using [HoughLineP](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp) to find lines in my frame and draw them back out.

Here is my code...  hope this helps.

```
    Mat mYuv = new Mat();
    Mat mRgba = new Mat();
    Mat thresholdImage = new Mat(getFrameHeight() + getFrameHeight() / 2, getFrameWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuv, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB, 4);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, thresholdImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
    Imgproc.Canny(thresholdImage, thresholdImage, 80, 100, 3);
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int threshold = 50;
    int minLineSize = 20;
    int lineGap = 20;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(thresholdImage, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);

    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) 
    {
          double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
          double x1 = vec[0], 
                 y1 = vec[1],
                 x2 = vec[2],
                 y2 = vec[3];
          Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
          Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

          Core.line(mRgba, start, end, new Scalar(255,0,0), 3);

    }

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(getFrameWidth(), getFrameHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    if (Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp))
         return bmp;
```

Comment: Hey i want to add a matrix on the highlighted portion in the image can you guide me?

Comment: @Brian ONeil can you tell me what are getFramHeight() and getFramWidth() methods Refers?

Comment: In Opencv SDK v3, you should use Imgproc.line instead of Core.line, Core.line does not exist any more.

Comment: Also in OpenCV 3.2 (I'm not sure about older version) you should iterate over `.rows()` (instead of `.cols()`), and then do `.get(x,0)` (instead of `.get(0,x)`). Otherwise you will get only first line.

Answer (score 1):

You draw the lines to the `mIntermediateMat` image, but returning `mRgba` image. That's why you don't see the lines.

The -1000..1000 range for  `b` is correct. `HoughLines` returns a line angle and distance from zero (a.k.a. *rho* and *theta*). To draw them, you need to convert them to two points. The 1000's are the image dimensions, if you would draw to a 2000x2000 image, increase them to 2000 or otherwise the lines will not cross the entire image.

`HoughLines` is different algorithm from `HoughLinesP`. `HoughLines` only finds lines, that cross the entire image. `HoughLinesP` returns shorter line segments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for visual studio, hope it helps.

```
void drawLines(Mat &input, const std::vector<Vec2f> &lines) {
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    float alpha = CV_PI/2-atan(input.rows/input.cols);
    float r_max;
    float r_min;
    float r = lines[i][0];
    float theta = lines[i][1];
    if (theta<alpha || theta>CV_PI-alpha) {
        r_max = input.cols*cos(theta);
        r_min = input.rows*sin(theta);
        if (r > r_max) {
            Point pt1(input.cols, (r - input.cols*cos(theta)) / sin(theta));
            Point pt2((r - input.rows*sin(theta)) / cos(theta), input.rows);
            line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
        }
        else if (r < r_max && r > r_min) {
            Point pt1(r / cos(theta), 0);
            Point pt2((r - input.rows*sin(theta)) / cos(theta), input.rows);
            line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
        }
        else {
            Point pt1(r / cos(theta), 0);
            Point pt2(0, r / sin(theta));
            line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
        }

    }
    else {
            r_min = input.cols*cos(theta);
            r_max = input.rows*sin(theta);
            if (r > r_max) {
                Point pt1(input.cols, (r - input.cols*cos(theta)) / sin(theta));
                Point pt2((r - input.rows*sin(theta)) / cos(theta), input.rows);
                line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
            }
            else if (r < r_max && r > r_min) {
                Point pt1(input.cols, (r - input.cols*cos(theta)) / sin(theta));
                Point pt2(0, r / sin(theta));
                line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
            }
            else {
                Point pt1(r / cos(theta), 0);
                Point pt2(0, r / sin(theta));
                line(input, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
            }
    }

}
```

Here are 2 graphs about the logic about my code I posted.

The explanation of alpha

[image: The explanation of alpha]

The explanation of r_max && r_min

[image: The explanation of r_max && r_min]

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.