# Convert Vec4i to Java openCV

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, vector

I'm new to OpenCV in Android. I'm trying to covert a C++ code into Java. I am stuck in some point that I cannot continue.

```
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
cv::HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 70, 30, 10);

    // Expand the lines
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Vec4i v = lines[i];
        lines[i][0] = 0;
        lines[i][1] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * -v[0] + v[1]; 
        lines[i][2] = src.cols; 
        lines[i][3] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * (src.cols - v[2]) + v[3];
    }
```

half way I converted.. upto the TODO

```
MatOfInt4 lines= new MatOfInt4();
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, 70, 30, 10);

int[] lineArray = lines.toArray();
// Expand the lines
//TODO 


 for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++)
    {
        int v = lineArray[i];
        lines.[i][0] = 0;
        lines[i][1] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * -v[0] + v[1]; 
        lines[i][2] = src.cols(); 
        lines[i][3] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * (src.cols() - v[2]) + v[3];
    }
```

which I'm confused is inside the for loop. when converted lines in to a Array it gives a int array. But inside the for loop again v is defined which should be a array. I didn't get this point. Can anybody please help me to get through this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have implemented this. but I can't find any lines on my resultant Mat. please guide –

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I managed to write the working code. with help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975315/2291506)

```
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int threshold = 70;
    int minLineSize = 30;
    int lineGap = 10;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(thresholdImage, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, threshold,
            minLineSize, lineGap);

    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {

        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double[] val = new double[4];

        val[0] = 0;
        val[1] = ((float) vec[1] - vec[3]) / (vec[0] - vec[2]) * -vec[0] + vec[1];
        val[2] = src.cols();
        val[3] = ((float) vec[1] - vec[3]) / (vec[0] - vec[2]) * (src.cols() - vec[2]) + vec[3];

        lines.put(0, x, val);

    }
```

Comment: @ssdehero please can you define what is the thresholdImage and the src fields?

Comment: @ssdehero I have implemented this. but I can't find any lines on my resultant Mat. please guide

Comment: @ssdehero how can i visualize this on my MAT android ?

Comment: Your code only gives me first line (I'm using OpenCV 3.2). You should iterate over `.rows()` (instead of `.cols()`), and then do `.get(x,0)` (instead of `.get(0,x)`).