# Contemporary way to make HoughLinesP work in JavaCV

Tags: scala, opencv, javacv

So, it seems the API changed over time.

I get as far as

```scala
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.{Mat, Point, Scalar}
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.{opencv_core, opencv_imgcodecs, opencv_imgproc}

val mat         = opencv_imgcodecs.imread("test-in.jpg")
val greyMat     = new Mat()
val lines       = new Mat()
opencv_imgproc.cvtColor(mat, greyMat, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY, 1)
val rho         = 1.0
val theta       = 1.0.toRadians
val thresh      = 50
val minLineLen  = 80
val maxLineGap  = 50

opencv_imgproc.HoughLinesP(greyMat, lines, rho, theta, thresh,
  minLineLen, maxLineGap)

for (i <- 0 until lines.rows()) {
  val pt1   = ??? : Point
  val pt2   = ??? : Point
  val colr  = new Scalar(0, 0, 255, 128)

  opencv_imgproc.line(mat, pt1, pt2, colr, 1, opencv_core.LINE_AA, 0)
}

opencv_imgcodecs.imwrite("test-out.jpg", mat)
```

But I don't know how to extract the points from the `lines` matrix.
For example, [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651756/convert-vec4i-to-java-opencv) suggests there such thing as a `MatOfInt4` which I don't find. Also, there is an answer that says I can do `lines.get(0, x)` on a `Mat`, a method that doesn't exist.

Then I find [another variant](https://github.com/liulongbiao/learn-javacv/blob/d391bfebaa5cbce32526e39439eb7c9a17f422a2/src/main/java/cn/strong/plays/javacv/ch07/Ex2HoughLines.java) that uses a `UByteRawIndexer`, but the cells in my matrix have three instead of four elements (this is perhaps because I call `HoughLinesP` and not `HoughLines`).

So how the heck do I get points from the `HoughLinesP` call? JavaCV is 1.2, OpenCV is 3.1.

---

If I query the `lines` matrix for its size, I get `rows = 19167, cols = 1`; I create an `Indexer` which appears to be a `UByteRawIndexer`, I get `sizes = [1958, 2196, 3]`. None of this makes sense to me. `lines` also has `depth = 5` and `type = 13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I created the indexer from the wrong matrix (input image instead of `lines`), that's why it was so large and of type unsigned-byte.

Creating the indexer from the `lines` matrix gives an `IntRawIndexer` with rows corresponding to number of lines, one column, and third dimension is of size 4, giving x1, y1, x2, y2:

```scala
  val indexer: IntRawIndexer = lines.createIndexer()

  for (i <- 0 until indexer.rows().toInt /* lines.rows() */) {
    val x1    = indexer.get(i, 0, 0)
    val y1    = indexer.get(i, 0, 1)
    val x2    = indexer.get(i, 0, 2)
    val y2    = indexer.get(i, 0, 3)

    println(s"x1 = $x1, y1 = $y1, x2 = $x2, y2 = $y2")

    val pt1 = new Point(x1, y1)
    val pt2 = new Point(x2, y2)
    val colr  = new Scalar(0, 0, 255, 128)

    opencv_imgproc.line(mat, pt1, pt2, colr, 1, opencv_core.LINE_AA, 0)
  }
```