# Is there a way to retrieve information from the camera on an android device?

Tags: java, android

What I'm wondering is if I snap a picture of an analog gauge is there a way I can get the camera to pull information about the position of the needles on the gauge?

Take an analog alarm clock for instance. If I wanted to snap a picture of the clock and based on the position of the hour and minute hands receive a digital time where would I start?

If anyone has any information on this subject or can point me in a direction that would be excellent.

Comment: I hope i am wrong but I think there is no easy approach to that task. Based on my knowledge you have to implement some computer vision algorithm on your own to determine that.

Comment: Cool Idea, Get the image from cam and do some thing like edge detection with opencv

Comment: OpenCV seems the most promising. It's definitely a place to start anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the only way to do so is using OpenCV

Most of the code is in C++ or Python, but I found a sample in Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925698/android-opencv-drawing-hough-lines).

Read about the OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).

Looks kinda complicated, wish you luck implementing it!